# How use selenium capturescreen and save into jenkins project?

Tags: java, maven, selenium, jenkins

I tried many ways and i still stuck.
I use code:

```
File f = new File("reports.png");
selenium.captureEntirePageScreenshot(f.getAbsolutePath(), "");
```

I tried also

```
protected String dir_path = System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

and no results. I cant find any images in jenkins project folder. 
I tried

```
*iexplore
```

but then i got error cuz selenium cannot make screenshot when is with iexplorer. So i changed to

```
*firefox
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jenkins sets [some environment variables when executing a job](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-JenkinsSetEnvironmentVariables). You are probably looking for the WORKSPACE variable.